# RRDTool 'graph' command throws Glib and Pango error, installed with Homebrew on Mac OS X

Tags: homebrew, glib, rrdtool, pango

The question is:

**How do I make RRDTool generate graphs on Mac OS X ?**

I installed `rrdtool` using `homebrew` on Mac OS x 10.6.8.

I'm able to create a database, update some data and fetch the data, but I'm not able to generate a graphs for it.

It looks like problem with `glib` and `pango`.

Both libraries are installed with `homebrew`.

I'm using:

- RRDTool 1.4.7
- Glib 2.34.2
- Pango 1.30.1

When I  run this:

```
rrdtool create datafile.rrd DS:packets:ABSOLUTE:900:0:10000000 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:9600 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:4:9600 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:24:6000
rrdtool update datafile.rrd N:12322
rrdtool graph graph.png DEF:pkt=datafile.rrd:packets:AVERAGE LINE1:pkt#ff0000:Packets
```

I get:

```
(process:34285): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:34285): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:34285): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:34285): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed
(process:34285): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_fontset_foreach: assertion `PANGO_IS_FONTSET (fontset)' failed
(process:34285): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderCoreText', script='latin'
(process:34285): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:34285): Pango-WARNING **: couldn't load font "DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,monospace,Courier Not-Rotated 8", modified variant/weight/stretch as fallback, expect ugly output.
(process:34285): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:34285): Pango-ERROR **: Could not load fallback font, bailing out.
./test.sh: line 9: 34285 Trace/BPT trap          rrdtool graph graph.png DEF:pkt=datafile.rrd:packets:AVERAGE LINE1:pkt#ff0000:Packets
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it can't find the fonts it needs. I tried manually installing DejaVu Sans Mono but no luck. It might be looking for those fonts in some specific location, outside of the normal OS X fonts dir.

P.S.: Looks like upgrading Pango might fix this, but the new version doesn't seem to be in brew repos yet: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13587

Comment: This works now, under OS X 10.8.3, pango 1.34.0, glib 2.36.1, and rrdtool 1.4.7. Still having trouble?